# UNIX command for reversing lines in file and storing it in another file

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I know tac is the command to reverse the order of the lines in file, however, I would like to know, how to store it in a different location. For-example: reverse the contents of file2, which is;

```
line3
line2
line1
```

and store it in file1. what is the UNIX command to do that?

Comment: You should learn about [redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
tac file2 > file1
```

`>` redirects the stdout of the *command* (`tac file`) to `file1`.

Comment: **Thanks!!** everyone for the answers

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of redirecting the output:

```
tac file2 > file1
```

If you are not familiar with redirection, `>` basically means that the result is stored in `file1` instead of appearing in your screen.

Answer (score 2):

```
tac file2 > file1
```

This ought to do it.

There are however more than one ways of doing it. i.e :

```
gawk '{ L[n++] = $0 } END { while(n--) print L[n] }' file2 > file1
```